# How programmatically to press Cancel button of SearchBar or return it to initial state?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, searchbar, uisearchbardelegate

What I need is that after taping on Search button, the searchBar returns to its initial state, so I can get to any UI element in one tap. Because currently I need to tap anywhere on screen once before I have ability to interact with other UI elements.
I've tried searchBar.resignFirstResponder() and searchBar.endEditing(true) and other UIView.endEditing, but it won't work. Thanks for advance!

For example,

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //search products, reload table and then:

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

UPDATE: Found the solution! `searchController.isActive = false`

Comment: Did you assigned `searchBar.delegate` to `self` in view controller?

Comment: Yeap, all delegate methods work fine.

Comment: `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` _should_ work perfectly fine. Just make sure you are conforming to the `UISearchControllerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: I've added UISearchControllerDelegate, but it doesn't help. searchBar.resignFirstResponder() still not working. I've updated my post with solution thats works for me. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to hide `Cancel` button after you clicked it. If yes please try this.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = nil
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: No, I don't need to hide it, I need to "tap" it programmatically, e.i. I need programmatically to cancel search. I've updated my post with solution already, but thank you for your answer)